# Can compiler make some function constexpr on its own?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, compiler-optimization, c++20

Can compiler evaluate a function that is not marked as `constexpr` at a compiler time, or all function without `constexpr` that are not inline will only be evaluated at a runtime?

Comment: A compiler is allowed to do that under certain situations yes.

Comment: Lotta people asking about `constexpr` lately it seems. Under the as-if ruler the compiler is free to evaluate a function at compile-time if it can determine that the result is knowable then, you don't _have_ to mark the function `constexpr` for this to occur.

Comment: The [As-if Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if). TL;DR: If the observable behaviour described by the code is not changed, the compiler can do whatever it wants to the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A compiler is allowed to evaluate some functions at compile time even if not marked as `constexpr`, yes. For example:

```
int foo() {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) result += i;
    return result;
}
const int s = foo();
```

The compiler can optimize the initialization of `s` by simply giving it the value 5050.

However, the compiler cannot allow you to use the result of `foo()` as a template argument (as if you had simply written `5050`), because it's not a valid constant expression. It must issue a diagnostic.

In other words, `constexpr` does not control whether a function may be evaluated at compile time. It controls whether a function is allowed to be called in a context that requires a constant expression.

Comment: [Simple demo of above](https://godbolt.org/z/r8bWcGYYj). See how `main` doesn't even bother calling `foo`.